# JsonParseException when trying to run spring boot

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, exception

Using the following command:
`java -jar target/spring-boot-config-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.application.json='{"server":{"ip":"192.168.145.78"}}'`
I get a `org.springframework.boot.json.JsonParseException: Cannot parse JSON` exception. I have no idea why, my command seems to be correct. Could anybody help me with this.  My application is simple:

```
public class SpringBootConfigApplication {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringBootConfigApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConfigApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Value("${server.ip}")
    String serverIp;

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner values() {
        return args -> {
            log.info(" > The Server IP is: " + serverIp);
        };
    }
}
```

The full stacktrace is:

```
        at org.springframework.boot.json.AbstractJsonParser.trimParse(AbstractJsonParser.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.json.AbstractJsonParser.parseMap(AbstractJsonParser.java:36)
        at org.springframework.boot.json.YamlJsonParser.parseMap(YamlJsonParser.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor.processJson(SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessEnvironment$0(SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:97)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:176)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(SpringApplicationJsonEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
        at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1507)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:374)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:332)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at be.brzyktom.springbootconfig.SpringBootConfigApplication.main(SpringBootConfigApplication.java:16)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotations in outer string and escape them when defining keys and values

```
java -jar target/spring-boot-config-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.application.json="{\"server\":{\"ip\":\"192.168.145.78\"}}"
```

Comment: Should be the case with Windows. Wonder whether same is required with a unix type environment

Comment: It works, but I wonder know why Spring official website uses single quotations? [2.2. JSON Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.command-line-args)

Comment: @LHCHIN, the doc mentions that those commands are run on a UNIX-based shell. Double quotes are for Windows.